# Put List of data in HttpResponseMessages Content .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an api which download a text file.
It works fine and save data in my text file.
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LQXd.jpg)

**so far what i have done given below:**

```
string data= "1";
HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = new StringContent(data);

result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "file.txt";
return result;
```

**what I want:**

I want to put a List in my result.Content. Sample list data like this:

```
List<BlobUploadModel> list= new List<BlobUploadModel>();

BlobUploadModel models = new BlobUploadModel();
models.FileName = "1";
list.Add(models);
BlobUploadModel models1 = new BlobUploadModel();
models1.FileName = "2";
list.Add(models1);
```

In my text file, It shows:

[result image want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ppLL.jpg)

How to do this?

Comment: @JeroenHeier where is list of data saved in result content. ? Can u tell me the line number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text file in your example image isn't showing a list - it's just showing a text file which contains data separated by a newline.

With that in mind, one way to extract some newline-separated data from your list could be:

```
// The filenames from the list
var filenames = list.Select(model => model.FileName);

// Filenames joined together in a newline-separated string
var data = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, filenames);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear I will answer what I think it is and if it's not please tell me in the comments.

What you have as a `List<T>` is a separated structure of data in memory which can't be saved in a text file. What you can save in a file is a `string`.

There are many ways to do this but this is the simplest in your case:

```
var dataAsString = string.Join("\n", list.Select(obj => obj.FileName));
```

you can now save `dataAsString` in file.

Comment: its not creating new line in text file.

Comment: It shows  output in the same line :    12. I want a new line before 2.